# MacOS: How to delete network services from command line?

Tags: macos, terminal, network, bash

I have several dozens of non-existent network services that appear in the network panel in System Preferences.

I have generated a list of network services with:

```bsh
networksetup -listallnetworkservices

## output:
# "Ethernet Adaptor (en12)"
# "Ethernet Adaptor (en13)"
# ...
# "Ethernet Adaptor (en156)"
```

Now trying to delete a service with e.g.

```bsh
networksetup -removenetworkservice "Ethernet Adaptor (en156)"
```

results in the following output:

```bsh
You cannot remove Ethernet Adaptor (en156) because there aren't any other network services on Ethernet Adaptor (en156).
** Error: The parameters were not valid.
```

Selecting a service in the Network applet and deleting it by clicking the <kbd>➖</kbd> button works fine.

Can this be done from the command line?

Comment: Does the presence of these interfaces cause any functional networking problem using your Mac? I admit, there are a lot of superfluous adaptors listed here and it is primarily an aesthetic concern. Do you use an Ethernet Adaptor, and if so, what brand? Perhaps the adaptor itself is not Apple-compatible, and is causing this 'stacking up' of adaptors in the list.

Comment: Sometimes the Ethernet adapter won't be detected after waking up and needs to be unplugged and plugged in again, but otherwise works reliably. Used with two different adapters, a UGreen ethernet-USB-C (detected as AX88179A) and another one TP-Link UE300 (USB-C).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
networksetup -deletepppoeservice "Ethernet Adaptor (en156)"
```